# Бесконечная отправка сообщений в HandlerThread

Tags: android, android-handler

Как можно бесконечно, раз в секунду, отправлять сообщение в HandlerThread?

Comment: Запустить цикл с задержкой в секунду? `new Thread { public void run() { while(true) {Thread.sleep(1000); /*Тут отправляем сообщение*/ }}}.start();`? Вообще можно по разному, главное знать зачем вам это нужно - какую задачу вы хотите этим решить?

Comment: В приложении вычисляются, по хосту IP4 и IP6, и отправляются в адаптер в виде списка.

Comment: Сразу после включения Wi-Fi, IP4 быстро вычисляются, IP6 - долго. У меня 56 хостов, и секунд 10 вычисляются IP6 для них, поэтому приходится вычислять в цикле. Для вычисления ip использую - InetAddress.getAllByName(host)